# Passing Parameters to and Executing global functions stored in an array

Tags: javascript, function

I have this global variable which contain function names. I am able to execute the function without parameters, but after passing some parameters, I get this error below.
"*Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*"

```
//Globally Called and refilled with function names
var function_name = new Array();

//This is the function that executes the var that contains function name
function execute(){
    var function_count = function_name.length;
    while (function_count--) 
    {
        window[function_name[function_count]](arguments);
    }
}

//This is how I add the function with its parameters
function_name.push("GetStatusDetails("+ sampleData +")");
```

Could you guys guide me with this I am newby in javascripting. Using the function above. Thanks everyone.

Comment: where are you calling `exexute` function?

Comment: from button click events and others... I want it like that way, I am just having problem how to pass a parameter.

Comment: Please see the last line of code above. If you have suggestions on how I pass the parameters. Am I doing it wrong? Please help..

Comment: You are passing the parameter incorrectly. You are pushing something like `"GetStatusDetails()"` into the array, so calling `window['GetStatusDetails()']` rather than `window['GetStatusDetails']`

Comment: No, my only concern is on how to pass parameter into my function. window['GetStatusDetails'] works well my only problem is how can I add parameters on my function name. thanks.

Comment: One option is to have the `function_name` array hold an object like `{ name: "GetStatusDetails", args: [somearg, other arg] }` and then call `window[function_name[function_count].name].apply(null, function_name[function_count].args)`

Comment: Hi with some changes in your proposed code. It worked  `           var function_count = function_name.length;

                                

                                while (function_count--) {
                                    window[function_name[function_count].name](function_name[function_count].args);
                                }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use arguments like this. This results in the arguments pseudo-array being passed as the first parameter. You need to do

```
window[function_name[function_count]].apply(window, arguments);
```

However, as mentioned in a comment, you also need to store a pure function name in your `function_name` array, and pass the arguments to `execute`, as in

```
function_name.push("GetStatusDetails");
execute(sampleData);
```

But why are you passing function *names* around? Just pass the functions around. So:

```
function_name.push(GetStatusDetails);
```

Then you call it directly, instead of pulling it out of the `window` object by name:

```
function_name[function_count].apply(window, arguments);
```

If you want to queue up function+params for later execution, then try something like:

```
//Array of functions to be called
var function_array = new Array();

//This is the function that executes the functions in the array
function execute(){
    var function_count = function_array.length;
    while (function_count--) 
    {
       function_array[function_count]();
    }
}

//This is how I add the function with its parameters
function_array.push(function() {
    GetStatusDetails(sampleData);
});
```

It would be better programming practice to encapsulate some of this along the following lines:

```
var FunctionQueue = {
    _queue: [],
    queue : function(fn) { this._queue.push(fn); },
    execute: function() { var fn; while (fn = this._queue.pop()) { fn(); } }
};

FunctionQueue.queue(function() { GetStatusDetails(sampleData); });
FunctionQueue.execute();
```

Comment: I want to pass the params during this procedure "function_name.push(GetStatusDetails);", but your answer is the closest to others suggestions.

Comment: Hi Sir torazaburo, My fullest respect to your code sire. It is just the best thing i've ever seen since. I've googled everywhere and your code is the most stunning. Thank you so much. Just an additional question sire, is this._queue.pop() dose this line of code removes the function name in the array list? Is there any way without deleting the array name in the _queue? I look forward for your answer thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
function_name.push("GetStatusDetails("+ sampleData +")"});
```

Here you're not pushing back a function but the result of the function call `GetStatusDetails(sampleData)`. `window` doesn't contain a key of the signature, so trying to find it with `window[...]` returns `undefined`. When you try to call it with `window[...](arguments)` that's how you got the error, because you can't "call" `undefined`.

`sampleData` should be passed into `execute()` at the call sight and you should be pushing back the name of the function:

```
function_name.push("GetStatusDetails");
```

Moreover, `arguments` is an array of the arguments, not the actual arguments. <strike>So `GetStatusDetails()` will have to go through the array to find the actual argument.</strike> Go see @torazaburo's answer that gives the correct solution.

Comment: Okay, let me explain it well... This is how I add the function name including its parameters function_name.push("GetStatusDetails("+ sampleData +")"); and this is how I execute it by calling execute(). And That will execute the pushed parameter name including its parameters but it fails. Now, my question is am I passing it wrong to the global variable which is the storage of function and supposedly including its parameters. Please. Thanks.

Comment: @user3932204 No, you're not adding the function name including its parameters, you're just passing in the string `"GetStatusDetails(x)"` (where `x` is `sampleData`). This function is never called (I wrongly said that in my answer which I now edited), but when its looked up with `window[["GetStatusDetails(x)]"` that expressions returns `undefined` because window doesn't contain a property named `"GetStatusDetails(x)"` but rather the function name `"GetStatusDetails"`. You need to pass the actual argument to `execute` (i.e `execute(sampleData)`)